# How to reset and alow to upload a the files using ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ng2-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload to upload files. It's working fine for me. I need to handle the error on the server side and reset the file uploader. How can I achieve this? Following are the codes I am using

**HTML**

```
        <div class="progress progressbar" style="height:10px;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s button_gray" (click)="uploader.cancelAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.isUploading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
      </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s button_gray" (click)="uploader.clearQueue()" [disabled]="!uploader.queue.length">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
      </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-s" (click)="uploader.authToken=authToken ;uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
      </button>
```

**Typescript**

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
          file.withCredentials = false;
          if (this.target) this.target.value = '';
        };
        this.uploader.onErrorItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onErrorItem(item, response, status, headers);
        this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onSuccessItem(item, response, status, headers);
      }

  let data = JSON.parse(response); //success server response
    console.log(data)
    this.showSnackBar('Successfully Uploaded file.');
    this.router.navigate(['/result'])
  }

  onErrorItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
    let error;
    if (response != undefined && response.length > 0)
      JSON.parse(response); //error server response
    else
      error = response;

    console.log(error)
    this.showSnackBar('Error on Upload the file.');
  }
```

Now, if there any failure then I am not able to upload a file again.

Comment: was this problem solved?

Comment: @just Shadow It's resolved.

Comment: Could you please provide the solution? We wouldd be very grateful to you for that.    P.S. it's completely okay to answer your own question in stackoverflow.

Comment: @Just Shadow "this.btnFileUpload.nativeElement.value = ' ' " this way i just rest the file uploader.

Comment: I solved It By this Code:
```javascript
    this.uploader.queue.pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you solved the problem but still i want to share whole solution for community

1- add this to the component

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
```

2- Add this declaration to component

```
@ViewChild("dummyID", { static: false }) 
myInputVariable: ElementRef;
```

3- in HTML file, give an ID to the particular element(i used #dummyID)

```
<input #dummyID type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

4- and then, you able to reach the element where you want in component, it's best practice to use it in **onWhenAddingFileFailed** method of ng2-file-upload

```
this.uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = item => {
//some code
//some code

 this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reset/empty the queue.

```
this.uploader.queue = [];
```